# C# HttpWebRequest Medium Blog returns 403 Forbidden but Site is Open

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403, medium.com-publishing-api

Medium blog pages are available on Chrome, IE etc... browsers but I can not send a web request with this code blog. It returns 403 Forbidden. By the way this method was working properly a couple of days ago. I changed my IP address numerious times, thought they might have banned my IP address but did not work.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://medium.com/@coinbaseblog");
request.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
   return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://medium.com/@coinbaseblog");
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Rigor/1.0.0; http://rigor.com)";
var result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: This solution was the one that work for me in the end. UserAgent suddenly became important for my web request, yet last week it wasn't. Strange...

Comment: Adding user agent help me too.

Answer (score 0):

http status code 403 indicates that server has understood the request but refuses to authorize it. Even if you are reauthenticating it will make no difference. This is similar to http status code 401 but in this case reauthentication works just fine. You may be authenticated but the resource which you are trying to access is restricted for you.